# Loading Image View From Http Server

Tags: java, android, http, picasso

Sorry im totally New to the Http, i Hardly Could Write a Http Server With Examples i have seen, and Im Trying to Download Images from this Http Server with Picasso Lib, but it seems Doesnt Work, here is my Server :

my content is : D:\Users\Default and im trying to load Default.jpg into iv:

```
public class SimpleHttpServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
server.createContext("/info", new InfoHandler());
server.createContext("/get", new GetHandler());
server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
server.start();
}

 static class InfoHandler implements HttpHandler {
public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
  String response = "Use /get to download an Image";
  t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
  OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
  os.write(response.getBytes());
  os.close();
}
  }

 static class GetHandler implements HttpHandler {
 public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

  // add the required response header for an Image file
  Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
  h.add("Content-Type", "image/jpg");

  // a PDF (you provide your own!)
  File file = new File ("D:/Users/Default/Default.jpg");
  byte [] bytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  bis.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);

  // ok, we are ready to send the response.
  t.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
  OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
  os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
  os.close();
}
 }
}
```

and loading it from picasso like this:

```
  Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.103:8000/D:/Users 
  /Default/Default.jpg")).into(iv);
```

Which are my Mistakes and how funny they are? :P

Comment: please provide log - have you perhaps forgot to add internet permission?

Comment: One obvious thing is that your URI should be `http://192.168.1.103:8000/get`, but we'll need the error log to trace your problem.

Comment: there is no error log mate, just doesnt load any thing

Comment: if it be http://192.168.1.103:8000/get so how can i tell which item do i want?

Comment: If you enter the URL into your browser, do you see the image?

Comment: when i enter 192.168.1.103:8000/Default.jpg , it says "no context Found for the request"

Comment: Well first off, you hard-coded the file that the server will return, so you don't need the file location in your Uri.... you would use /get at the end... it even says so in your code... `String response = "Use /get to download an Image";`. Also, you need to add:

Comment: is this content type ture ?     Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
      h.add("Content-Type", "image/jpg");

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, you hard-coded the file that the server will return, so you don't need the file location in your Uri.... you would use /get at the end... it even says so in your code... `String response = "Use /get to download an Image";`. Also, you need to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to your manifest file if you have not already... It would be helpful FYI to post a log, not just ask whats wrong and not give any hints.

Comment: i have premission dude and it throws exception if i dont have